# is there a way to put a possible cooldown on this

Tags: node.js, discord

```
 dmGuild.members.forEach(member => {
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(member.id == bot.user.id) return;
            console.log(`DMing ${member.user.username}`);
            member.send(`${msg}  ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999)}`);
        }, 0);
    });
```

I need help finding a way to limit each time this is used. ex: i use the command and they are all messaged at once, is there anyway to send a dm with a 5000ms ratelimit in between?

Answer (score 0):

You can take the `index` from the `forEach` callback and use it when specifying the `setTimeout` delay.

```
dmGuild.members.forEach((member, i) => {
    setTimeout(function(){
      if(member.id == bot.user.id) return;
      console.log(`DMing ${member.user.username}`);
      member.send(`${msg}  ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999)}`);
    }, (i+1) * 5000);
});
```

If the error `TimeoutOverflowWarning` occurs, try to create timeouts gradually using recursion.

```
function fn(members, i = 0) {
  var member = members[i];

  if(member.id != bot.user.id) {
    console.log(`DMing ${member.user.username}`);
    member.send(`${msg}  ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999)}`);
  }

  if (i < members.length) {
    setTimeout(() => fn(members, i + 1), 5000);
  }
}

fn(dmGuild.members);
```

Comment: hi when i attempted that i received this error (node:13940) TimeoutOverflowWarning: 2.143324247614423e+22 does not fit into a 32-bit signed integer.
Timeout duration was set to 1.

Comment: Did the solution help you? @sai10r